# React hook setState and useContext is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update a react context with an array

this is the cartcontext

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
 
import UniqueString from "../lib/unique-string";
import suspender from "../lib/suspender";
import db from '../db';
const uid = new UniqueString();

// set up the database when this function is called

// const CartDBContext = React.createContext(setUpDatabase())




const emptycart = {"454":{"test"}}

const CartContext = React.createContext([emptycart]);


// function to get all meals in the DB
async function getAllItemsFromDB() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

 
        var allItems = db.table("cartitems").toArray().then((itemArry) => {
            console.log("items in cart ",itemArry) 

            if (!itemArry || !itemArry.length) {
                // array does not exist, is not an array, or is empty
                // ⇒ do not attempt to process array
                 resolve([])
              } else {
                  resolve(itemArry)
              } 

        })
     })
}

// using our suspender here
const resource = suspender(getAllItemsFromDB());

// The component itself
function CartContextProvider({ children }) {
    // reading data from suspender
    const items = resource.data.read() || [];
    console.log("all items from suspender", items, resource)

    // state to store list of items in the object Store
    const [itemsList, setItemsList] = useState(items);

    // if the itemList is null, umnount the component
    // else return the appropriate JSX
    return (
        // pass the mealsList state and its setter as context values
        <CartContext.Provider value={{ itemsList, setItemsList }}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default CartContextProvider;
export { CartContext };
```

this is index.jsx where the context is used

```js
import React, { useContext,useState,useEffect,useRef ,Suspense } from "react";

import CartContextProvider, { CartContext }  from "../components/CartContextProvider";

function Index(){


...
    const [itemsList, setItemsList] = useContext(CartContext);
    
 useEffect(() => { 
runIndexDb(data).then(async result => {
                            console.log("ItemList is ", itemsList)

                            console.log(result)
                            
                            
                            setItemsList(itemsList => [...itemsList, result]);
                        }) 
                        
      })


...
}

The print out of console.log 
for itemsList

ItemList is  {454: "test"}

result 

0: {id: "00010164533955", name: "Hilsinger Company Sport Band - Black", productimg: "http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/44e902de-30f8-40f3…9fdb.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff", unitofissue: "each", quantity: 2, …}
1: {id: "00014381104394", name: "A House Divided: Season 1 (DVD)", productimg: "http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/99cfec5c-634e-4e26…4465.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff", unitofissue: "each", quantity: "1", …}
2: {id: "00016500590958", name: "One A Day Men's 50+ Mini Gels, Multivitamins for Men, 80 Ct", productimg: "http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/7d44d419-bd6f-4808…b7ea.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff", unitofissue: "each", quantity: "1", …}
3: {id: "00022141041599", name: "Mepps Dressed Aglia Inline Spinner, Silver & Gray, 1/4 oz", productimg: "http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a0ce2579-300a-4536…0d63.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff", unitofissue: "each", quantity: "1", …}
```

the code is throwing an error at setItemsList

> > Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setItemsList is not a function

I tried many different methods but no solution

what am I doing wrong and how can I updated the itemsList with the array from above?

Answer (score 1):

### `useContext` returns an `object` and not a list.

If you do it like so it should work.

### Try to replace:

`const [itemsList, setItemsList] = useContext(CartContext);`

### With：

`const { itemsList, setItemsList } = useContext(CartContext);`

Comment: I still get error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setItemsList is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you used useContext in a component that isn't wrapped by the context provider (using useContext in the same component with return context provider).

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."